# x server startx error?

Tags: 10.10, command-line, xorg

```
root@thewhitewox:~# startx

X.Org X Server 1.7.6
Release Date: 2010-03-17
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.24-29-server i686 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux thewhitewox 2.6.18-238.9.1.el5.028stab089.1 #1 SMP Thu Apr 14 14:06:01 MSD 2011 i686
Kernel command line: quiet
Build Date: 20 October 2011  03:05:54PM
xorg-server 2:1.7.6-2ubuntu7.10 (For technical support please see ww w.ubuntu . com/support)
Current version of pixman: 0.16.4
        Before reporting problems, check http: //wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue Nov 15 00:50:32 2011
(==) Using config directory: "/usr/lib/X11/xorg.conf.d"

Fatal server error:
xf86OpenConsole: Cannot open /dev/tty0 (No such file or directory)


Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
         at http ://wiki.x.org
 for help.
Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.

 ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log
```

What does this mean and how can I  fix it?

Answer (score 2):

There is no /dev/tty0 file, that usually means two things:

- You are running a virtual server with no VGA (and ssh-ing to it, of course)
- There is some problem with udev

If you are in a real machine, you can try to reinstall udev.

Answer (score 0):

Based on "2.6.24-29-server" you are running Hardy 8.04.

What graphics card do you have?  Run:

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

and paste that back.